# searching a character in a string

Tags: c++

How can i search a character `"` in a string.

Comment: What do you expect to find in that character? Also always remember the fourth amendment. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use string::find() function. visit [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) for more info

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string str ("foo\"bar");
  string str2 ("\"");
  size_t found;
  //you may want to do str.find('"') if you are only looking for one char.
  found=str.find(str2); 
}
```

it's very important to escape the " character inside defined strings.

Comment: Or instead of allocating a new string to hold `"\""` you could use `string::find()` with the single character `'"'`.

Answer (score 2):

The best you can do for finding a character in an unsorted string is a linear search:

```
for each index in the string:
       if the character at that index matches the search criteria:
              report the current index
report not found
```

There is, of course, a function for doing that already: [std::string::find](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/find), which will return [std::string::npos](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/npos) if the character is not found; otherwise, the function will return the index at which the character is first found. There are also variations of find like [std::string::find_first_of](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/find_first_of), [std::string::find_last_of](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/string/find_last_of), and their "not_of" variants.

Answer (score 2):

[`string::find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple solution:

```
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;  

int findChar(char c, string myString)
{
   pos = myString.find(c); // Find position in the string (to access myString[pos])
   return int(pos);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that **doesn't have any depedency** with library in C++

```
char * foo = "abcdefg";

char cf = 'e'; // Char to find

int f = 0; while (*(foo + f++) != cf); // f is 5
```